# fast filter method in python

Tags: python, list, filter

I want to filter two list with any fastest method in python script. I have used the built-in `filter()` method for this purpose. but it is quite slow and taking too much time because I have very big list, I think more than 5 million item in each list or may be more. 
I do not know how I will make it. Please if anybody have idea or write small function for it.

Answer (score 18):

Maybe your lists are too large and do not fit in memory, and you experience [thrashing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thrash_(computer_science)).
If the sources are in files, you do not need the whole list in memory all at once. Try using *[itertools](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.ifilter)*, e.g.:

```
from itertools import ifilter

def is_important(s):
   return len(s)>10

filtered_list = ifilter(is_important, open('mylist.txt'))
```

Note that *ifilter* returns an *iterator* that is fast and memory efficient.

[Generator Tricks](http://www.dabeaz.com/generators/) is a tutorial by David M. Beazley that teaches some interesting uses for *generators*.

Answer (score 5):

If you can avoid creating the lists in the first place, you'll be happier.

Rather than

```
aBigList = someListMakingFunction()
filter( lambda x:x>10, aBigList )
```

You might want to look at your function that makes the list.

```
def someListMakingGenerator( ):
    for x in some source:
        yield x
```

Then your filter doesn't involve a giant tract of memory

```
def myFilter( aGenerator ):
    for x in aGenerator:
        if x > 10: 
            yield x
```

By using generators, you don't keep much stuff in memory.

Answer (score 2):

I guess filter() is as fast as you can possibly get without having to code the filtering function in C (and in that case, you better code the whole filtering process in C).

Why don't you paste the function you are filtering on? That might lead to easier optimizations.

Read [this](http://www.python.org/doc/essays/list2str.html) about optimization in Python. And [this](http://docs.python.org/api/api.html) about the Python/C API.

Comment: Both your links are dead.

Answer (score 2):

Before doing it in C, you could try [numpy](https://numpy.org/). Perhaps you can turn your filtering into number crunching.

Answer (score 2):

Filter will create a new list, so if your original is very big, you could end up using up to twice as much memory.
If you only need to process the results iteratively, rather than use it as a real random-access list, you are probably better off using
ifilter instead. ie.

```
for x in itertools.ifilter(condition_func, my_really_big_list):
    do_something_with(x)
```

Other speed tips are to use a python builtin, rather than a function you write yourself.  There's a itertools.ifilterfalse specifically for the
case where you would otherwise need to introduce a lambda to negate your check.  (eg "ifilter(lambda x: not x.isalpha(), l)" should be written "ifilterfalse(str.isalpha, l)")

Answer (score 2):

It may be useful to know that generally a conditional list comprehension is much faster than the corresponding lambda:

```
>>> import timeit
>>> timeit.Timer('[x for x in xrange(10) if (x**2 % 4) == 1]').timeit()
2.0544309616088867
>>> timeit.f = lambda x: (x**2 % 4) == 1
timeit.Timer('[x for x in xrange(10) if f(x)]').timeit()
>>> 
3.4280929565429688
```

(Not sure why I needed to put f in the `timeit` namespace, there.  Haven't really used the module much.)

Comment: I just ran the two following lines in comparison: [e for e in lst if e[1] in olist]  # filter(lambda e: e[1] in olist, lst) . . . and they both took exactly the same (excruciating) amount of time.

Answer (score -1):

```py
numbers = [-2, -1, 0, 1, 2]

def extract_positive(numbers):
    positive_numbers = []
    for number in numbers:
        if number > 0:  # Filtering condition
            positive_numbers.append(number)
    return positive_numbers

extract_positive(numbers)
```